# return a conditional statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

i have this kind of method:

```
function() {
  if (condition) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I thought of returning the condition itself , to make it more clean, and maybe more readable.
like this:

```
function() {
  return (condition);
}
```

is this considered a good practice?

Comment: Yes _(a former teacher of mine would yell at us when we used your first example)_. However, it won't always return a boolean (ie: `3 && 4` will return `4`). If you absolutely need a boolean, use double negation: `return !!(condition);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no other code than just returning true/false then yes, return just the condition.

```
function() {
    return (condition);
}
```

Just as you said, it is more readable, less code. I wouldn't even call it good practice, it's more like the first code is a bad practice.